# How to customize automatic marshaling in Spring RestTemplate to produce/modify XML headers (encoding, DOCTYPE)

Tags: java, xml, spring, marshalling, resttemplate

I'd like to find how to influence how Spring **automatically** marshals Java objects to XML when sending a POST request via `RestTemplate`. Particularly, how to configure what is in the XML headers (`encoding`, `DOCTYPE`, ...).

There are plenty of questions closely touching the topic ([Include DOCTYPE for Spring Jaxb2Marshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19365002/2886891), [How to add DOCTYPE and xml processing instructions when marshalling with JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2919294/2886891), [how to add DOCTYPE in jaxb marshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45344450/2886891), [How to declare doctype ,xml version and encoding in XML file using DOM parser in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33703068/2886891)) but none of them seems to help here.

[image]

I am aware that I may marshal the object to XML string first and then send the XML string. However, I'd like to use the automatic marshaling as it seems more elegant and proper.

I have a class like

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyRequest")
public class MyRequest {
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    String field1;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    String field2;
    ...
}
```

The code sending the HTTP POST request is like:

```java
final MyRequest requestBody = new MyRequest("VALUE1", "VALUE2");

final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.ALL));
final HttpEntity<MyRequest> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);

return restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestHttpEntity, MyResponse.class);
```

When I intercept what is sent, it is something like this:

```
POST /webservice HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml, */*
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: example.com:8080
Content-Length: ...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyRequest field1="VALUE1" field2="VALUE2">
</MyRequest>
```

and what I want to receive is

```
POST ...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE MyRequest SYSTEM "MyRequest.dtd">
<MyRequest field1="VALUE1" field2="VALUE2">
</MyRequest>
```

Question: **How can I customize the marshaling without completely avoiding the automagic behavior of Spring RestTemplate?** I want to change the `encoding`, remove the `standalone` attribute (where does it come from?) and add the `<!DOCTYPE>` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the XML converter that RestTemplate uses with a customized one:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
for (int i = 0; i != converters.size(); i++) {
    if (converters.get(i) instanceof Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter) {
        Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter(){
            @Override
            protected void customizeMarshaller(Marshaller marshaller) {
                marshaller.setProperty( "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders", "<!DOCTYPE MyRequest SYSTEM \"MyRequest.dtd\">");
                // add other customizations
            }
        };
        converters.set(i, xmlConverter);
        break;
    }
}
```

Wrap the whole thing in a method annotated with @Bean @Qualified, and use that to autowire the RestTemplate wherever you need it, if you have many places to inject it to

Comment: @HonzaZidek I'm not aware of a better way to get a hold on the XML converter that the `RestTemplate` uses - this is the way we're been using in our projects (we've customized the JSON converter, though). `RestTemplate` only exposes the list of `HttpMessageConverter`s, but has no means to get a hold of any specific one, as far as I know. BTW, just for the record, using `instanceof` doesn't really count as "reflection"

Comment: @HonzaZidek As for your other question, you can customize the same `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` instance to also enable the DTD support. Again, I wish I has a nicer-looking way to get a hold of the converter, but this is all Spring is exposing to us. Maybe newer Spring version have added something for this use case?

Comment: See also the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/47854054/2886891 (by @M.Deinum), it is also applicable.