# Spring RestTemplate cannot unmarshal XML containing "<!DOCTYPE ... dtd>"

Tags: java, xml, spring, unmarshalling, resttemplate

I call an old web service provided by a third party. I am using Spring `RestTemplate`:

```java
HttpEntity<MyRequest> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
MyResponse response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestHttpEntity, MyResponse.class);
```

I receive an XML (which format I cannot influence, it's a third party service) as a response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE MyResponse SYSTEM "http://example.com:8080/some/path/MyResponse.dtd">

<MyResponse>
    ...
</MyResponse>
```

The `postForEntity()` method throws the exception

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: 
    Error while extracting response for type [class com.example.MyResponse] and content type [text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1];
nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
    Could not unmarshal to [class com.example.MyResponse]: null;
nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

- with linked exception:
     [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 10;
     DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature
     "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to true.]
```

I found the only sensible reference to the `http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl` feature here: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#disallow-doctype-decl

**Question: How can I customize the unmarshaling without completely avoiding the automagic behavior of Spring RestTemplate?** I want to force the unmarshaler to accept XML containing  element with DTD reference.

This question is strongly related to my other question [How to customize automatic marshaling in Spring RestTemplate to produce/modify XML headers (encoding, DOCTYPE)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47836310/2886891), but the solution proposed there is not easily applicable here.

Comment: Just set that property to false... You can configure the `HttpMessageConverter` to do so https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html#setSupportDtd-boolean- . By default this property is set to `false` disabling DTD support, this has to do with security implications when enabling DTD support.

Comment: @M.Deinum It works like magic (supposed you meant set that property to *true* :) ), thanks! I have not noticed the method before. Please make it an answer, I am keen to accept it! And do you have also such a simple answer to my related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47836310/2886891? The Alex Savitsky's answer *does* work, but it looks more like a hack to me.

Comment: See the answer here, especially the second part that should also answer your other question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the [`Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html#setSupportDtd-boolean-) disables the DTD support (and with that XML Entity support). The reason for this is that it has security implications, see [SPR-11376](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11376).

To enable it on the [`Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11376) you can set the `supportDtd` property to `true` to enable it again. But be aware this will also open up some potential security issues!.

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter() {
    Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter converter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportDtd(true);
    return converter;
}
```

This should be enough to (re)configure support without needing to add any additional configuration. One thing to remember is that this will configure the globally available `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` and as such will impact all controllers and `RestTemplate`s you might want to use.

Instead of doing this you could also use the `RestTemplateBuilder` which you should use when creating an instance of the `RestTemplate` to only influence that specific `RestTemplate`.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate yourRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter converter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportDtd(true);

    return builder.messageConverters(converter).build()
}
```

This way you can configure it specific for that instance of the `RestTemplate` and configure what you like.

Comment: Could you please now make a kind of a summary in your answer and we will both delete our comments from here so we keep SO clear for the other readers. I will then accept your answer, which helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: What should I modify... The answer, as is, is correct. Your results differ because you are using the `RestTemplateBuilder` in a way you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Maybe add some notes about how the behaviour differs if you use `RestTemplateBuilder` as a (default) bean or if you instantiate it manually. Because I did not know there are methods like `additionalMessageConverters()` and `messageConverters()` and `defaultMessageConverters()` and others may benefit from it, too.